# How to edit Firefox scroll bar to behave like Chrome's

Tags: firefox, scrolling

In Chrome, the way I usually scroll a page is by clicking anywhere below where the scroll bar is on  the right hand side, and it will gradually scroll down the page. however in Firefox, doing this will immediately jump to that part of the page. Is there anyway to modify it to behave like it does in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Options in Firefox, scroll down to the "Browsing" section on the "General" tab, and then select "Use smooth scrolling". If it is not selected, then scrolling will behave exactly the way the OP says it does.

See the highlighted option in the screenshot below:
[image]